# Is it possible to develop an iOS app to block incoming calls?

Tags: ios

I want to develop a blacklist App. How can I detect an incoming call? Is there any solution to detect an incoming call ?

Comment: you can't yet unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this so, Apple never approve this, your app must be jailbreak. if you want this you need use hook from MobileSubstrate. I find sample code in [blocking calls and sms](https://github.com/shyang/cate)

Comment: Thanx sumit but is it working...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with iOS.

Comment: an app that messes with people's calls won't get approved for the app store, nor does Apple provide an API for that.

Answer (score 0):

In 6 months, such an app would likely be irrelevant.